# Horizontal lines not spanning entire length of row in tabularx environment

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I'm trying to create a multi-columned table to provide some summary of data, the code below is what I currently have.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{|l||ll||ll|}
\hline
             & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Top Column 1} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Top Column 2}      \\  \hline
ROW 1        &                     &                   &               &                \\ \hline
ROW 2        &                     &                   &               &                \\ \hline
ROW 3        &                     &                   &               &                \\ \hline
ROW 4        &                     &                   &               &                \\ \hline
ROW 5        &                     &                   &               &                \\ \hline
ROW 6        &                     &                   &               &                \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

However in the resulting table, the horizontal lines do not span the entire row.

[image]

I suspect this is due to my headers (i.e. the use of 'l' and the separators), but I can't find a solution despite looking only. Why do the horizontal lines not span the entire row length?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue when wrapping a document around your fragment (which is your job, actually). Also, the given fragment does not have the `Yes No` etc. content like the screenshot...

Comment: `tabularx` tables must have at least one `X` column otherwise it has no way to make the table the specified width. But data tables with no linebreaking in the cells it is better to just use a standard `tabular`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c||p{1cm}|p{1cm}||p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}\hline %\cline{2-5}
   & \multicolumn{2}{c||}{Top Column 1}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Top Column 2}\\\hline
   Row 1 & Yes & No & Yes & No \\ \hline
   Row 2 & 124 & 6 & 124 & 6 \\ \hline
   Row 3 & 124 & 6 & 124 & 6 \\ \hline
   Row 4 & 124 & 6 & 124 & 6 \\ \hline
   Row 5 & 124 & 6 & 124 & 6 \\ \hline
   Row 6 & 124 & 6 & 124 & 6 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
```

[image]

Maybe it fits for you better ;)

Answer (score 0):

- as pointed in comment [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) comment above, `tabularx` had to have at least one `X` column:
- don't use `H` for table placement, it can make unexpected problems with white space on a the bottom of a page in table can't float
- don't use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` in float environment. it add unnecessary vertical space above and below table
- i suggest to omit vertical rules and for horizontal use rules from the package `booktabs`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{@{}l *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Top Column 1}
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Top Column 2}   \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
Row 1   & Yes   & No    & Yes   & No    \\
    \midrule
Row 2   & 124   & 6     & 124   & 6     \\
Row 3   & 124   & 6     & 124   & 6     \\
Row 4   & 124   & 6     & 124   & 6     \\
Row 5   & 124   & 6     & 124   & 6     \\
Row 6   & 124   & 6     & 124   & 6     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]